# Read the query string from URL and check the checkboxes with Yii2 and Js

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have a form as follows :
Category with foreach:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="<?=$category_items->id?>" name="category[]" id="<?=$category_items->id?>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="<?=$category_items->id?>"><?=$category_items->name?></label>
</div>
```

and Brands  with foreach :

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="<?=$brand_items->id?>" name="brand[]" id="<?=$brand_items->id?>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="<?=$brand_items->id?>"><?=$brand_items->name?></label>
</div>
```

I send the form as a GET and a query is done and the necessary information is displayed and then it is read by a query string in JavaScript and the categories and brands checkbox is checked if it was available in the url according to regex : `let regEx = /\w+\[]=/g;` ,

But the problem is that when Yii2 pagination is used, it changes the url, for example, **category[]=24&category[]=30** becomes **category[0]=24&category[1]=30&page=2** and I read it again with regex `let regEx = /\w+\[+\d+]/g;` so that the checkboxes can be checked. It works, but when clicked in the URL bar and hit enter, it does not work normally.

my Js code :

```
const url2 = window.location.href;

var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf('?');
url = new URL(document.location.href);
let regEx = /\w+\[+\d+]/g;

if (document.location.href.match(regEx)) {

    var categories = document.location.href.substr(i + 1).replace(/category+\[+\d]=/g , '').split('&');
    var brands = document.location.href.substr(i + 1).replace(/brand+\[+\d]=/g, '').split('&');

    $('input[name="category[]"]').prop('checked', function () {
        return $.inArray(this.value, categories) !== -1;
    });

    $('input[name="brand[]"]').prop('checked', function () {
        return $.inArray(this.value, brands) !== -1;
    });

}
else{

    var categories = document.location.href.substr(i + 1).replace(/category+\[]=/g , '').split('&');
    var brands = document.location.href.substr(i + 1).replace(/brand+\[]=/g, '').split('&');

    $(`input[name="category[]"]`).prop('checked', function () {
        return $.inArray(this.value, categories) !== -1;
    });

    $(`input[name="brand[]"]`).prop('checked', function () {
        return $.inArray(this.value, brands) !== -1;
    });

}
```

Anyone have an idea? That either the information is sent as ( **category[0]&category[1] ...** ) & (  **brand[0]&brand[1] ...** )  from form to work properly in the url or the same code.
**Thanks**.

Comment: Set the HTML correctly in the PHP with all the corret checkboxes delivered in there correct state

Comment: @RiggsFolly How do you mean to write?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - checkboxes is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check GET params in your html code?

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="<?=$category_items->id?>" name="category[]" id="<?=$category_items->id?>" onChange="this.form.submit()" <?= (isset($_GET['category']) && in_array($category_items->id, $_GET['category'])) ? ' checked' : ''?>>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="<?=$category_items->id?>"><?=$category_items->name?></label>
</div>
```

This will work when page is refreshed.

How do you load another page? Do you use Pjax or something like that? If you use Pjax then you must include filter code in pjax container.

Or if you want to do it with JS then try something like that:

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
urlParams.getAll('category');
```

You can see browser support of URLSearchParams here -> https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/